# How to pass/store IEnumerable<ModelName> return value to controller variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> Below are the repository where defined empmodel type iEnumerable and executing some database command which returns the data successfully and now want to fetch this record on controller using variable but can't be fetched.

```
public IEnumerable<empModel> GetEditData(int id, int deployment_id)
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = conn_str;

        using (conn)
        {

            // Open connection
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            using (NpgsqlCommand command = common_repo.GetSqlCommandQuery("select * from get_data(" + id + ", " + deployment_id + ", 'data'); fetch all in \"data\";", conn))
            {
                using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read()) ;

                    // Go to next result set
                    dr.NextResult();

                    // Iterate through result set to get result set
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        yield return empModel.SetValues(dr);
                    }

                } // reader closed and disposed up here

            } // command disposed here

        } //connection closed and disposed here
    }
```

### now fetching this data in controller using

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //var lead_data = db.Leads.Find(lead_id);

        var lead_data = uow.LeadRepo.GetEditData(id,1);
    }
```

> this is showing no data.

Comment: one correction this is showing data but can to store in Lead_Data variable

Comment: Did you try to iterate IEnumerable?
Like use .ToList()?

Comment: can you send me some example.

Comment: Well, you have `GetEditData` that returns `IEnumerable<T>`, just use `ToList()` & `foreach` loop to fetch every data inside it.

Comment: @RahulGour  
var lead_data = uow.LeadRepo.GetEditData(id,1).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IEnumerable and yield return returns data when needed (Its Lazy). 
If you want to see data You have to load it (for example use .First() or .ToList())
You can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var lead_data = uow.LeadRepo.GetEditData(id,1).ToList();
}
```

[return-ienumerable-with-yield-return](https://coding.abel.nu/2011/12/return-ienumerable-with-yield-return/)